# Is it possible to have a condition in a JPA @Query statement to determine if a timestamp matches the current date?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an existing JPA @Query that I need to add an addition condition to the WHERE such that it'll only return rows where the current date matches that of a timestamp column. Basically wondering if something along the lines of this is possible:

```
@Query("SELECT .. " +
        "WHERE .. " +
                "AND isCurrentDay(c.completedTs))"
```

Otherwise can accomplish what I need with a native query.

Edit: My solution ended up being to use a Native Query like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ... " + 
"WHERE ... " + 
     "AND CONVERT (date, c.completedTs) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))", 
nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be it would be safer to do it through native queries using the `CURDATE` sql statement of the language you are writing in. For example, for MySQL + JPA it would look something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT .. " +
        "WHERE .. " +
                "AND WHERE DATE(`completed_ts`)=CURDATE()", 
       nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing this (for MS SQL Server):
    @Query(value = "SELECT ..." +
            "WHERE .." +
            " AND CONVERT (date, c.completedTs) = 
                    CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))" , 
      nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 0):

JPQL Exposes few functions to associate CURRENT date/time :

From the docs :

> CURRENT_DATE: This function returns the value of current date on the database server.
> CURRENT_TIME: This function returns the value of current time on the database server.
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: This function returns the value of current timestamp on the database server.

ref : [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e28847/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/internal/jpql/parser/DateTime.html)

These can be used in the following way to directly access current date

```
@Query("SELECT .. " +
        "WHERE .. " +
                "AND c.completedTs=CURRENT_DATE )"
```

Please note , AFAIK , these are vanilla functions and do not support expressions , i.e , you cannot do CURRENT_DATE-1.

Comment: Is this database-dependent? When I try that I get an exception:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'.

Comment: It is native to jpql parser so just referencing it directly should not be a problem.Make sure that nativeQuery is false.It will be translated when it is JPQL.